# PHP - move_uploaded_file replace spaces with %20

Tags: php, file-upload, spaces

I am using move_uploaded_file to upload a file, but when I upload a file with spaces it does not replace is with %20 and then I am stuck with the file name with spaces, how do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["logoHeader"]["name"]);
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));


        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["logoHeader"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check === false) {

                $error = 'File is not an image.';

                include('views/logos/index.php');

                break;

            }
        }

        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {

            $error = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.';

            include('views/logos/index.php');

            break;

        }

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logoHeader"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

            $error = 'Image has been uploaded.';

        }
        else
        {
            $error = 'Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.';

            include('views/logos/index.php');

            break;
        }
```

Comment: `%20` is just part of URL-encoding during the communication from the browser to the server, it's not supposed to be kept in the application.

Comment: afterwords I am saving the file path in a database, should I do that there?

Comment: No, it's only needed for browser-to-server communication, not anywhere else.

Comment: Its a request from a client....

Comment: You can use `$target_file = str_replace(' ', '%20', $target_file)` if you really want that in the filename.

Comment: You could do what @Barmar suggested, or replace all spaces with underscores and saving it as the filename also. That way it'll be file and database friendly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["logoHeader"]["name"]);
//new line
$target_file = checkName($target_file);
//end new line
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
//your code
```

and add checkName function

```
function checkName($name){
    if(preg_match("`^[-0-9A-Z_\.]+$`i",$name)){
        return $name;
    }else{
        $name = str_replace(' ', '%20', $name);
        return $name;
    }
```

But you are still not spared from other "incomprehensible" characters. How will you give the file if its name contains characters that are not allowed for URL?
For example: ÆÞΔΦÜЩЫž.jpg

Try to find more information about URL slug ;)